# rewrite simple python code efficiently

Tags: python

I have the following code, which is likely to be repeated. Meaning, i will need to search the entire log file during different parts of the code to see if two particular patterns exist in it. I cant always search for the patterns at once, at the start of the code.

But basically, below is what I have and I'm looking for ways to optimize it. assuming the logfile being read can be very huge in size.

```
    textfile = open(logfile, 'r')
    filetext = textfile.read()
    textfile.close()
    matchesBegin = re.search(BeginSearchDVar, filetext)
    matchesEnd = re.search(EndinSearchDVar, filetext)
    if matchesBegin is not None and matchesEnd is not None:
        LRangeA = SeeIfExactRangeIsFound()
        PatternCount = len(LRangeA)
        LRange = '\n'.join(LRangeA)
```

I know this can be optimized with the with option but i dont know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for optimization, use the [`mmap module`](https://pymotw.com/3/mmap/).

> Memory-mapping a file uses the operating system virtual memory system
>   to access the data on the file system directly, instead of using
>   normal I/O functions. Memory-mapping typically improves I/O
>   performance because it does not involve a separate system call for
>   each access and it does not require copying data between buffers – > the memory is accessed directly by both the kernel and the user
>   application.

```
import mmap
import re

# Create pattern with all, ignore case, and multi line flags.
# search for every instance of `stackoverflow` within a sentence.
pattern =  re.compile( rb'(\.\W+)?([^.]?stackoverflow[^.]*?\.)',
                       re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE )

# open file using 'with' which initializes and finalizes an instance
with open( log_file, "r" ) as file:
    # create new instance of mmap
    with mmap.mmap( file.fileno(), # fileno returns file descriptor for IO
                    0, # size in bytes for how much to map (if 0 then entire file)
                    access = mmap.ACCESS_READ # set access flag to read
                  ) as m: # name instance `m`
        matches = pattern.findall( m ) # find all patterns in mapped file
        print( "Matches: " + len( matches ) )
        for match in matches:
            print( match.group(0) )
```

If the file is truly massive, you could change the second argument (byte size to map) to better suite your needs.

Comment: thank you for this!  i have to shamefully admit though that im pretty new to python so most of what you typed here looks intimidating.  may i ask, how do i apply it directly to the code in my original post?

Comment: Replace the expression in `pattern`. Change or rename `log_file` and set it's value to the path of the file. Counting the total matches like so `len( matches )` which you should probably error check by using `if matches:`. In the `for loop` you do as you wish with however many groups you're trying to catch with your regex. If you need help go to http://www.RegEx101.com and visit the IRC channel; they're extremely active and love creating expressions.

Comment: i just tried running this on my Unix ubuntu host.  got a "AttributeError: __exit__" error.  I researched this and found it could be because the format you provided was meant for Windows OSes.  can you please help me modify your code to be Unix specific?